# UIImageJPEGRepresentation and UIImagePNGRepresentation both are slow

Tags: ios, nsdata, image-resizing, uiimagejpegrepresentation, uiimagepngrepresentation

Here i am converting my image to binary data by category on UIImage which have static method.My Problem is UIImageJPEGRepresentation and UIImagePNGRepresentation are very slow upto 6 second. I need 1 sec solution.Can Anybody help me.
  Here i pass my image to category method till its size reduce to less than or equal to 10kbs.

```
  -(NSData *)imageConvertToBinary :(UIImage *) image{

        NSLog(@"Image Convert  ");

        //UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, .000032);
         NSLog(@"Image Done  ");

        //Change size of image to 10kbs

        int size = imageData.length;
        NSLog(@"SIZE OF IMAGE:First %i ", size);
        NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, .0032);
        NSLog(@"Start while  ");
        int temp=0;
        while (data.length / 1000 >= 10) {
            image = [UIImage imageWithImage:image andWidth:image.size.width/2 andHeight:image.size.height/2];

            data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, .0032);
            temp++;
            NSLog(@"temp  %u",temp);

        }

        size = data.length;
        NSLog(@"SIZE OF IMAGE:after %i ", size);


        return data;

    }

and also i have category class on UIImage
@implementation UIImage (ImageProcessing)

+(UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image andWidth:(CGFloat)width andHeight:(CGFloat)height
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( CGSizeMake(width, height));
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,width,height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
@end
```

---

NSData *data ; 
 must be equal to something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reduce your code you were using two times more UIImageJPEGRepresentation try this

```
- (NSData *)imageConvertToBinary :(UIImage *) image{
    NSData *data ;
    NSLog(@"Start while  ");
    int temp=0;
    while (data.length / 1000 >= 10) {
        image = [UIImage imageWithImage:image andWidth:image.size.width/2 andHeight:image.size.height/2];
        data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, .0032);
        temp++;
        NSLog(@"temp  %u",temp);
    }
    NSLog(@"End while  ");
    int size = data.length;
    NSLog(@"SIZE OF IMAGE:after %i ", size);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: data has not been initialized